# Dependency Injection in Laravel 5 Package To Use or Not To Use

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I am developing a package for Laravel 5, I decided to benefit from dependency injection in my package when using the Core classes of Laravel, but after reading more and also having asked this question 
[Best approach for Dependency Injection in Laravel 5 package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834398/best-approach-for-dependency-injection-in-laravel-5-package)

Now I came up with the idea that if we are using `Facades` so much and calling static methods like `FaceadeName:nameOfMethod` the Container actually creates an object for us and calls its method, so to some extend using dependency injection for laravel for classes which are also available through the Facades are is almost useless.

For example having this class:

```
class MyController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{        
  public $text;
  public $lang;

 public function __construct()
 {         
   // Some codes here                            
}

public function myFunction(){
   $this->text = \Lang::get('package::all.text1');           
 }
}
```

doing this:

```
 App::bind('lang', function($app)
 {
    return new \Lang();
  });
```

and then in the function:

```
public function myFunction()
{
    $lang = \App::make('lang');       
    $this->text = $lang::get('package::all.text1');           
}
```

is almost useless because we bind something to container that is already bound there

It is not a great idea to change the `myFunction` to

```
 public function myFunction(\Lang $lang){
     $this->text = $lang::get('package::all.text1');           
 }
```

as well, it might look like method injection but it doesn't bring so much advantages. Therefore it would be better not to use `dependency injection` for `Facades` in Laravel. 
Please let me know if I am right or not and please argue my opinion with the right answer if I am wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facades provide a way of accessing the container through a class, so when you're accessing `\Lang::function()` you're actually calling `app('translator')->function()`. So in you're above example when you're binding the `Lang` facade into the container, you've then bound it twice, which isn't quite what you want.

All Laravel's functionality is already bound into the container and can be accessed by calling `app('object')`. You can see all the bindings here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/facades

For dependency injection, you shouldn't be trying to inject the facades, but rather the classes the facades are already referencing. So for example, the `\Lang` facade references `Illuminate\Translation\Translator` which is bound to the container as `translator`

In your classes you can do the following

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Translation\Translator;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    protected $translator;

    // Dependency injection example
    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $text = $this->translator->get('package::all.text1');
    }

    // Method injection example
    public function myFunction(Translator $translator)
    {
        $text = $translator->get('package::all.text1');
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for injecting the class. Among other things, it makes it a whole lot easier to test `myFunction()` and inject a mock `Translator`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, considering your answer,  does this method bring enough advantages to stick to it, and use core classes like that instead of using `Facades`, for example does it help the testing or any other possible advantages? ( I know it's almost a new question )

Comment: Using dependency injection makes things easier to test as you can pass mock objects directly into the class and/or functions. This also allows you to abstract layers away from the controller, which makes your code less framework dependent should you ever look to migrate in the future (The repository pattern is a good example of this)