# Laravel 5 Facades or Dependency Injection Pros and Cons

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, laravel-5

I am developing a package for Laravel 5, I decided to benefit form Dependency Injection in my package and it is easy to implement in Laravel particularly for `constructor injection`, but when it comes to `Facades` some new issues arise. when we have classes like

```
  class MyController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
 {        
   public $text;
   protected $lang; 

   public function __construct(\Lang $lang)
   {         
      $this->lang = $lang;
   }

   public function myFunction(){
     $this->text = $this->lang->get('package::all.text1');           
   }
  }
```

The code above doesn't work since the `Lang` is a `Facade`, therefore we have to change the code to this:

```
  use Illuminate\Translation\Translator

  class MyController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
 {        
   public $text;
   protected $translator; 

   public function __construct(Translator $translator)
   {         
      $this->translator = $translator;
   }

   public function myFunction(){
     $this->text = $this->translator->get('package::all.text1');           
   }
  }
```

The Question:
I need to know what are the advantages and disadvantage of using the facades against using the constructor injection

I also have checked this question:
[laravel - dependency injection and the IoC Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824673/laravel-dependency-injection-and-the-ioc-container) and laready asked this question: 
[Dependency Injection in Laravel 5 Package To Use or Not To Use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880388/dependency-injection-in-laravel-5-package-to-use-or-not-to-use)

you just can help as well with confirming the answer of the first question as well

Comment: I don't think you should inject a facade. AFAIK injections should only be made with interfaces.

Comment: I'm also having issues trying to use the Cache Facade within a package I'm building so will be interested in answers to this question.